# If condition using storage.set is not working in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

**Brief Explanation of what is happening:**  When I open the app on mobile, it directly takes me to `dashboard.html` from `login.html`

**What I am trying to achieve:**  When app is opened for the 1st time, after giving username and password, on success response username and password information is saved in local storage. From the next time when app is opened, app goes to login.html, in its `ngOnInit()` it checks if user is already logged in then it navigates to 'dashboard.html`else stays at`login.html` page.

But it takes me to `dashboard.html` even at the very first time after app is installed. What am I doing wrong ?

`login.ts` code:

```
  ngOnInit()
{

if(this.storage.get('user').then((val) => {
  if(val===''){
    console.log("this key does not exists");
    this.storage.set('user','');
  }
  else {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
    console.log('user::',val);
  }

    console.log("i am out of if");

 }))
 {

 }
{console.log('user',val);});
}
```

Please check my if condition and let me know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for all your `storage.get` code to be inside of an if statement, it's not even possible (as far as i know, maybe if you return a boolean), you just need this

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.storage.get('user').then((val) => {
    if (val === '') {
      console.log("this key does not exists");
      this.storage.set('user', '');
    } else {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
      console.log('user::', val);
    }
    console.log("i am out of if");
  });
}
```

Also you'll need to set your user as `''` the first time your app is opened, if you don't do this your `val` will be null and it'll fall to your else and your user'll gain access to DashboardPage everytime even without beeing logged or having an account at all.

So it would be better if you don't set your user as `''`, just don't set it and leave it to be null, then you can do as this

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.storage.get('user').then((val) => {
    if (val) {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardPage);
      console.log('user::', val);
    } else {
      console.log("this key does not exists");
    }
    console.log("i am out of if");
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and if users logs out, on logout `OnInit` i have passed `this.storage.set('user','');` , is this the right way or should i do something else ??

Comment: When the user logout you can clear your storage, set `user` to null, or remove `user` with `this.storage.remove('user')`.